# How to implement a spark sql udf as a function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to implement a `spark.sql.functions.udf` to do some complex filter.

I got some examples but most of them are simple and are implemented as closures. While it's not simple to control the return value in a closure.

Here's an exmaple:

```
val filterClosure: UserDefinedFunction = udf {
(ips: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) =>
  for (ip <- ips) {
    if (!(ip.startsWith("abc") || ip.startsWith("def"))) true
  }
  false
}

val ds = Seq((0, Array("hello", "baby", "word")), (1, Array("abcgod", "deftest"))).toDF("id", "words")
ds.filter(filterClosure($"words")).show()
```

The output is:

```
+---+-----+
| id|words|
+---+-----+
+---+-----+
```

So, how to implement it as a function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is in your anonimous function: it always returns false, because `false` is the last statement. So your loop does nothing at all. You solved this problem with function literal `filterFunction` and `return` in the loop. But it's not recommended to use `return` in Scala, and there are a lot of methods to interact with collections. So why don't you just use `exists` method?

```
val ds = Seq((0, Array("hello", "baby", "word")), (1, Array("abcgod", "deftest"))).toDF("id", "words")
val filterClosure = udf {
    (ips: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => ips.exists(ip => !(ip.startsWith("abc") || ip.startsWith("def")))
}

ds.filter(filterClosure($"words")).show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|              words|
+---+-------------------+
|  0|[hello, baby, word]|
+---+-------------------+
```

That's result.

It's strickly recommended not to write your own methods instead of ones included in Scala Collections API.

Comment: @Dimitry Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @secfree You are welcome:) https://pavelfatin.com/scala-collections-tips-and-tricks/ -- useful article from IntelliJ Scala plugin developer at JetBrains. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `udf` to wrap a defined function:

```
def filterFunction(words: mutable.WrappedArray[String]): Boolean = {
    for (wd <- words) {
        if (!(wd.startsWith("abc") || wd.startsWith("def"))) return true
      }
    false
}
val filterUdf = udf(filterFunction _)
ds.filter(filterUdf($"words")).show()
```

The output is correct:

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|              words|
+---+-------------------+
|  0|[hello, baby, word]|
+---+-------------------+
```